# cannot set pandas column values using series, sets everything to np.nan instead

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, nan

I have the following pandas (`pd`) dataframe:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6], 'z':[7,8,9]}, index=['one', 'two', 'three'])
> df
       x  y  z
one    1  4  7
two    2  5  8
three  3  6  9
```

and a Series:

```
s = pd.Series([99,99,99])
```

When I try to assign these values in `b` to some column in `df`, I don't get any error but all values in that column are set to `nan` instead:

```
> df['y'] = s
> df
       x   y  z
one    1 NaN  7
two    2 NaN  8
three  3 NaN  9
```

I have set dataframe column values many times before using this assignment technique, why doesn't this work (anymore)?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the index values in the `DataFrame` and `Series`: they don't match.
By default, any pandas index has integer values which count up from `0`, so if you don't modify them and the lengths of your column and `Series` match, there is no problem.

However, you modified the index values of `df` and set them to `['one', 'two', 'three']`.
You should make sure that:

- either the `Series` uses the same index as the `DataFrame`:

  ```
  > s = pd.Series({'one': 99, 'two': 99, 'three': 99})
  > df['y'] = s
  ```
- or, you can just use the (index-less) values in `s`:

  ```
  > df['y'] = s.values
  ```

to obtain:

```
> df
       x   y  z
one    1  99  7
two    2  99  8
three  3  99  9
```

Answer (score 0):

ICCU:

Another way of doing it. Please try df.assign

```
df.assign(y=s.values)
```

[image]